# Dynamically Changing the Size of the Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, struct, new-operator, dynamic-allocation

I have the following structure

```
typedef struct DeviceInfo
{
    char[30] name;
    char[30] serial Number;

}DeviceInfo;

I am doing this    

DeviceInfo* m_DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo[4];

// Populate m_DeviceInfo
```

Then I wanted to re size `m_DeviceInfo`  to 6 and want to preserve the
Previous 4 Value as well.

How to do it in c++ ?

Comment: Try to use STL.Which will solve your problem?

Comment: I am quite surprised that several answers suggesting vectors (including mine) have been downvoted!!

Comment: -1 for not being honest about this being homework and for not mentioning restrictions ("STL is not allowed").

Comment: KerrekSB Its mistake not about honesty and Not Honesty.I forget to update the question abt it.anway I respect your judgement and Accept your -Ve Vote as lesson.Thanks Kerrek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with regular arrays. I suggest you to use [vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) which is able to grow as you add more elements to it (so you don't even have to specify initial size).

Comment: STL is not allowed Do we any Other Solution.

Comment: I guess you will have to implement array reallocation by yourself. Standard strategy of "resizing" arrays is to allocate new array with size doubled when the old array runs out of space, copy all contents from old array and free the old array.
In fact, this is pretty much implementing your own vector.

Answer (score 3):

The good C++ way is to use an appropriate container for that. Apparently, you should use the [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) container, e.g:

```
std::vector<DeviceInfo> m_DeviceInfo;
m_DeviceInfo.resize(4);
```

This requires some constraints on your *DeviceInfo*. In particular, it should have a constructor without arguments, and copy constructors...

And your question is badly phrased. You certainly don't change `sizeof(DeviceInfo*)` which is probably 4 bytes on a 32 bits machine, and 8 bytes on a 64 bits one.

Answer (score 3):

1) Make a new array of size that fits, and copy all elements of the old array to the new one.

2) Use the `std::vector` (my recommendation).

Answer (score 3):

`m_DeviceInfo` points to an array of `DeviceInfo` of 4 elements. There is no resizing with arrays. Instead you should delete and create it with 6 elements.

```
DeviceInfo * m_DeviceInfo2 = new DeviceInfo[6]; 
memcopy( m_DeviceInfo,m_DeviceInfo2, 4 );
delete[] m_DeviceInfo;
```

But you should use a vector.

```
std::vector<DeviceInfo> m_DeviceInfo;
// or 
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DeviceInfo>> m_DeviceInfo;
```

To resize it

```
m_DeviceInfo.resize(m_DeviceInfo.size()+ 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options in your problem and it depends if you want to use STL or not.

```
typedef struct DeviceInfo
{
   char[30] name;
   char[30] serial Number;

} DeviceInfo;
```

With STL:

```
//requires vector.h
vector<DeviceInfo> m_deviceInfo;

DeviceInfo dummy;
dummy.name = "dummyName";
dummy.serialNumber = "1234"; 

m_deviceInfo.insert(m_deviceInfo.begin(), dummy); 
//add as many DeviceInfo instance you need the same way
```

or without STL:

```
//implement this 
DeviceInfo* reallocArray(DeviceInfo* arr, int curItemNum, int newItemNumber)
{
   DeviceInfo* buf = new DeviceInfo[newItemNumber];

   for(int i = 0; i < curItemNum; i++)
     buf[i] = arr[i];

   for(int i = curItemNum; i < newItemNumber; i++)
     buf[i] = null;
}

//and in your main code
DeviceInfo m_DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo[4];

m_DeviceInfo = reallocArray( m_DeviceInfo, 4, 6 );
```

Comment: You forgot arguments to `reallocArray`.

Answer (score 2):

The best possible solution is using **vector** in your program.

Refer this site http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html#VECTOR

This site will help you to solve your problem.

Here you can push the data.No need to bother about the size of structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
DeviceInfo m_DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo[4];
```

should be:

```
DeviceInfo* m_DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo[4];
```

#### A better alternative would be the use of `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<DeviceInfo> vec;

//populate:
DeviceInfo inf;
vec.push_back(inf);
vec.push_back(inf);
//....
```

Answer (score 0):

well there are several ways to do this, but 
you should use the realloc function in c++. it will reallocate contiguous memory and also copies the value of previous memory into the new ones. for example:

```
temp_DevInfo = (DeviceInfo*) realloc (m_DeviceInfo, (2) * sizeof(struct DeviceInfo));
free(m_DeviceInfo);
m_deviceInfo = temp_DevInfo;
```

you do 2 * sizeof(DeviceInfo) because you want to add 2 more, plus the previous 4 is 6.
then you should free/delete the previous object. 
and finally set old pointer to point to the new object you just allocated.

that should be the gist of it

look at the documentation of realloc.

Comment: this is not c++, or the correct way to do it in c++..  (I didn't downvote)

Comment: The answer isn't that bad, this is not the C++ way, but the C way. But C++ was designed to be (mostly) a superset of C, so you can still do it the old way... Maybe useful on platforms without `new` (whatever that may be)